# How to determine if a string contains any matches of a list of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Hi say I have a list of strings:

```
var listOfStrings = new List<string>{"Cars", "Trucks", "Boats"};
```

and I have a vehicles options which has a Name field.

I want to find the vehicles where the name matches one of the items in the listOfStrings.

I'm trying to do this with linq but can't seem to finish it at the moment.

```
var matchingVehicles = Vehicles.Where(v => v.Name == one of the listOfStringItem)
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Vehicles.Where(v => listOfStrings.Contains(v.Name))
```

Comment: This works for a very short list of strings, but it scales badly.

Answer (score 12):

Use a `HashSet` instead of a `List`, that way you can look for a string without having to loop through the list.

```
var setOfStrings = new HashSet<string> {"Cars", "Trucks", "Boats"};
```

Now you can use the `Contains` method to efficiently look for a match:

```
var matchingVehicles = Vehicles.Where(v => setOfStrings.Contains(v.Name));
```

Answer (score 6):

would this work:

```
listOfStrings.Contains("Trucks");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var m = Vehicles.Where(v => listOfStrings.Contains(v.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an [Inner Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx):

```
var matchingVehicles = from vehicle in vehicles
                       join item in listOfStrings on vehicle.Name equals item
                       select vehicle;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Vehicles.Where(vehicle => listOfStrings.Contains(vehicle.Name))
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string contains one of these characters (Boolean output):

```
var str= "string to test";
var chr= new HashSet<char>{',', '&', '.', '`', '*', '$', '@', '?', '!', '-', '_'};
bool test = str.Any(c => chr.Contains(c));
```